# Firebase data insert issue. Data is not inserted properly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to insert a POJO to Firebase. However, some of the fields don't seem to be parsed into Firebase, but there is no warning or error.

I have this POJO:

```
public class Group {
    public String name;
    public String admin;
    public List<String> addedUsers;
    public List<String> invitedUsers;

    public Group(String name, String admin, ArrayList<String> addedUsers, ArrayList<String> invitedUsers) {
        this.name = name;
        this.admin = admin;
        this.addedUsers = addedUsers;
        this.invitedUsers = invitedUsers;
    }

    public Group() {
        // Default constructor required because we have a non-default constructor as well.
    }
}
```

I upload to Firebase by doing so:

```
DatabaseReference groupRef = ref.child("Groups");
ArrayList<String> addedUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
addedUsers.add("email1@gmail.com");
addedUsers.add("email2@gmail.com");
ArrayList<String> invitedUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
Group newGroup = new Group("GroupName",
        "email1@gmail.com", addedUsers, invitedUsers
);

groupRef.push().setValue(newGroup);
```

I end up with this object in Firebase:

[image]

I have a secondary issue now, I manually inserted the data into Firebase, but now I cannot map the Lists onto my Java Object, and are mapped as null, I know I am able to download the data fine;

Comment: [Firebase treats empty objects as non-existent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408416/how-to-handle-empty-arrays-in-firebase), which might explain why `invitedUsers` is not showing. But, I believe [you need to have getters for all of your class members](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340202/how-does-firebases-setvalue-work-for-objects-in-java). Also, it is good practice to declare your non-static member variables as `private`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean that lists are not supported, as it seems that [they are supported.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

> Basic write operations
>
> For basic write operations, you can use setValue() to save data to a
> specified reference, replacing any existing data at that path. You can
> use this method to:
>
> Pass types that correspond to the available JSON types as follows:
>
> - String
> - Long
> - Double
> - Boolean
> - `Map<String, Object>`
> - `List<Object>`
> - Pass a custom Java object, if the class that defines it has a default
>   constructor that takes no arguments and has public getters for the
>   properties to be assigned.

Comment: I missed this point thx for correcting. But lists are not reachable one by one. So maps are more useful I guess

Answer (score 0):

Firebase supports key value mapping. So lists are not supported. Change it to Map  type, keep email addresses as key and assign a boolean value true or false.

Comment: I tried changing it to Map type, however this did not work either the uploaded value was the same. Additionally I can't use email addresses as keys in firebase as they contain periods which are not allowed in data paths

Comment: Isn't ur email string? It must be. map = new Hash Map... and map.put (email, true). If emails are different it will not override

Comment: It is, but email contains @ and . which are invalid characters for firebase keys, the hashmap will easily accept it but it will not upload to firebase

Comment: Instead of emails map users so Map <User, Boolean>. It will be more flexible and light